# Wait for it to resolve promise and then insert neatly

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I've been watching all morning because this code doesn't work for me.

I want once the promise is resolved, the "then" get its last inserted ID (the promise) and neatly insert into the other table.  Currently first paints all the promise and then just then or disorderly ...

```js
con.query("SELECT ID FROM wp_posts ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 0,1;", function(err, result, fields) {
  console.log(result);
  for (var i = 0; i < getData.length; i++) {
    var source = getData[i]["source"];
    var text = getData[i]["text"];
    var quality = getData[i]["quality"];
    new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      var sql = "INSERT INTO `wp_posts` ( `post_author`, `post_date`, `post_date_gmt`, `post_content`, `post_title`,`post_excerpt`, `post_status`,`comment_status`, `ping_status`,`post_password`, `post_name`,`to_ping`,`pinged`, `post_modified`, `post_modified_gmt`,`post_content_filtered`,`post_parent`, `guid`,`menu_order`, `post_type`, `post_mime_type`,`comment_count`) VALUES (1, '" + fhoy + "', '" + fhoy + "', '', '" + make + "','', 'publish', 'closed', 'closed','','" + make + "','','', '" + fhoy + "', '" + fhoy + "','', '" + result[0].ID + "','','0', 'dt_links','' ,0);";
      con.query(sql, function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        resolve(result);
        console.log("1 registro link insertado");
      });
    }).then(function() {
      //new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      con.query("SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type='dt_links' ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 0,1;", function(err, result, fields) {
        console.log(result);
        var sql = "INSERT INTO wp_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (" + result[0].ID + ",'_dool_url', '" + source + "'),(" + result[0].ID + ",'_dool_type','" + text + "'),(" + result[0].ID + ",'_dool_quality','" + quality + "');";

        con.query(sql, function(err, result) {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log("1 registro link meta insertado");
        });
        // });
      });
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Be warned, your SQL queries are vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Sure, but that's not the point, thanks.

Comment: For starters, change ALL your `var` declarations to `let` or `const`.  That will help a lot with asynchronous operations inside a loop.  Basically, except for very, very rare circumstances, you should not be using `var` any more.  Then, I would switch to mysql2 and exclusively use the promise interface to the database as that would drastically simplify sequencing multiple operations.

Comment: Why are you referencing `result[0].ID` in your first query inside the `for` loop?  This is inside the loop, but this will have the same value every time.  That does not seem correct.  In fact, your first query is the same every time through the loop.  Why?  Is it supposed to be `getData[i].ID`?

Comment: There is more code before that, a couple of MySQL queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how much cleaner things can be if you use the promise-based interface built into mysql2 to sequence all your operations properly:

```
// using mysql2/promise
// parent function must be declared async

try {
    let posts = await con.query("SELECT ID FROM wp_posts ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 0,1;");
    console.log(posts);
    for (const post of posts) {
        const source = post.source;
        const text = post.text;
        const quality = post.quality;

        let sql = "INSERT INTO `wp_posts` ( `post_author`, `post_date`, `post_date_gmt`, `post_content`, `post_title`,`post_excerpt`, `post_status`,`comment_status`, `ping_status`,`post_password`, `post_name`,`to_ping`,`pinged`, `post_modified`, `post_modified_gmt`,`post_content_filtered`,`post_parent`, `guid`,`menu_order`, `post_type`, `post_mime_type`,`comment_count`) VALUES (1, '" + fhoy + "', '" + fhoy + "', '', '" + make + "','', 'publish', 'closed', 'closed','','" + make + "','','', '" + fhoy + "', '" + fhoy + "','', '" + posts[0].ID + "','','0', 'dt_links','' ,0);";
        await con.query(sql);
        console.log("1 registro link insertado");

        let result = con.query("SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type='dt_links' ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 0,1;")
        console.log(result);

        sql = "INSERT INTO wp_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (" + result[0].ID + ",'_dool_url', '" + source + "'),(" + result[0].ID + ",'_dool_type','" + text + "'),(" + result[0].ID + ",'_dool_quality','" + quality + "');";
        await con.query(sql);
        console.log("1 registro link meta insertado");
    }
} catch(e) {
    // handle all db errors here
}
```

Not only is this a lot simpler to read and understand, but it also sequences each of your database operations and collects all the error handling to one place (you had basically no error handling before).

List of changes:

1. Switch to mysql2/promise so we can use the built-in promise interface.
2. Use `async` and `await` to make sequencing asynchronous database operations a lot simpler to code
3. Use `try/catch` to catch and handle all database errors in one place (you had no reasonable error handling before)
4. Switch to `for/of` as a more convenient way to iterate an array
5. Replace all `var` declarations with `const` or `let` as appropriate.
6. Switch syntax from things like `getData[i]["quality"]` to `getData[i].quality` because it's just simpler and the quotes and brackets are not needed around a simple property name.

Open Issues:

1. Your first query in the `for` loop is exactly the same every time through the loop.  That does not seem correct.  The only reference to `result` in that original query was `result[0].ID`, but that will be exactly the same value every time through the loop so something is apparently not correct with that.  I don't think you want to be inserting the same record everytime through the loop.

Comment: I get: result[0].ID
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Answer (score 0):

So the SQL injection vulnerabilities aside, you may have a better time with a promisified `con.query` function, here called `queryP()`.

I'm not sure I could capture the original logic of your code since it was reusing `result`, etc., but the idea should be there.

**Do note though** that there is a possible problem here in that if multiple concurrent requests modify `wp_posts`, the post IDs you're modifying may change. You may want to [look at this to get the last inserted ID](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#getting-the-id-of-an-inserted-row).

```js
function queryP(con, sql, variables = []) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    con.query(sql, variables, (err, result, fields) => {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err);
      }
      return resolve({ result, fields });
    });
  });
}

async function processDataThing(con, result, dataThing) {
  var source = dataThing["source"];
  var text = dataThing["text"];
  var quality = dataThing["quality"];
  const r1 = await queryP(
    con,
    "INSERT INTO `wp_posts` ( `post_author`, `post_date`, `post_date_gmt`, `post_content`, `post_title`,`post_excerpt`, `post_status`,`comment_status`, `ping_status`,`post_password`, `post_name`,`to_ping`,`pinged`, `post_modified`, `post_modified_gmt`,`post_content_filtered`,`post_parent`, `guid`,`menu_order`, `post_type`, `post_mime_type`,`comment_count`) VALUES (1, '" +
      fhoy +
      "', '" +
      fhoy +
      "', '', '" +
      make +
      "','', 'publish', 'closed', 'closed','','" +
      make +
      "','','', '" +
      fhoy +
      "', '" +
      fhoy +
      "','', '" +
      result[0].ID +
      "','','0', 'dt_links','' ,0);",
  );
  console.log("1 registro link insertado");
  const r2 = await queryP(
    con,
    "SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type='dt_links' ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 0,1",
  );
  const result2 = r2.result;
  const r3 = await queryP(
    con,
    "INSERT INTO wp_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (" +
      result2[0].ID +
      ",'_dool_url', '" +
      source +
      "'),(" +
      result2[0].ID +
      ",'_dool_type','" +
      text +
      "'),(" +
      result2[0].ID +
      ",'_dool_quality','" +
      quality +
      "');",
  );
}

// ...

async function doThings(con, getData) {
  const { result } = await queryP(con, "SELECT ID FROM wp_posts ORDER BY ID DESC 
LIMIT 0,1");
  const dataThingPromises = getData.map(dataThing => processDataThing(con, result, dataThing));
  return await Promise.all(dataThingPromises);
}

// ...

doThings(con, getData).then(() => console.log("All done!"));
```

Comment: Thanks, i test with this. But, i get: const { result } = await queryP(con, "SELECT ID FROM wp_posts ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 0,1");
                   ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

Comment: Yes, that code will also need to be in an async function... Let me just wrap that up for you.

Comment: @FiorellaGamarraAguado Edited.

Comment: You will likely need to use the linked "get the last inserted ID" operation to get the correct post to attach the metadata to.